# Mean of value by days

Tags: python-3.x, time, pandas-groupby

I have the follow dataset

```
                   dVal              eVal
0        2015-01-01 00:00:00.000  3.622833
1        2015-01-01 01:00:00.000  3.501333
2        2015-01-01 02:00:00.000  3.469167
3        2015-01-01 03:00:00.000  3.436333
4        2015-01-01 04:00:00.000  3.428000
5        2015-01-01 05:00:00.000  3.400667
6        2015-01-01 06:00:00.000  3.405667
7        2015-01-01 07:00:00.000  3.401500
8        2015-01-01 08:00:00.000  3.404333
9        2015-01-01 09:00:00.000  3.424833
10       2015-01-01 10:00:00.000  3.489500
11       2015-01-01 11:00:00.000  3.521000
12       2015-01-01 12:00:00.000  3.527833
13       2015-01-01 13:00:00.000  3.523500
14       2015-01-01 14:00:00.000  3.511667
15       2015-01-01 15:00:00.000  3.602500
16       2015-01-01 16:00:00.000  3.657667
17       2015-01-01 17:00:00.000  3.616667
18       2015-01-01 18:00:00.000  3.534500
19       2015-01-01 19:00:00.000  3.529167
20       2015-01-01 20:00:00.000  3.548167
21       2015-01-01 21:00:00.000  3.565500
22       2015-01-01 22:00:00.000  3.539833
23       2015-01-01 23:00:00.000  3.485667
24       2015-01-02 00:00:00.000  3.493167
.........
.........
```

I want do a mean, by day, of the column eVal. 
First step if transform the dVal column  to datetime.

```
time['dVal'] = pd.to_datetime(time['dVal'])
```

Next I set the datetime column as the index

```
time.index = time['dVal']
```

Finally I count mean for each day

```
me = time.resample('D').mean()
```

The mean calculated it's wrong.

```
dVal         eVal
2015-01-01  4.014973  --> The correct mean of the first day is 3.5
2015-01-02  4.006548
2015-01-03  4.010406
2015-01-04  4.034531
```

Comment: works fine for me `eVal
dVal                
2015-01-01  3.506160
2015-01-02  3.493167
`

Comment: You follow my step? Your eVal column is a float like mine? If you try min() or max() function, give you the correct resoult? Bacause I have a problem with this two others functions

Comment: `dVal    datetime64[ns]
eVal           float64
dtype: object`

Comment: I try to use different function but i don't arrive to the correct result. I try to use: time.set_index('dVal').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).mean().dropna() but it give me the same result above. The dtype is the same yours

Comment: If I use  only `me = time.resample('D')` and next I do a describe function for understand the situation in general `me.describe()`, all the value are wrog ( like max, min,mean).